# Do you know "sample[::-1]" mean? in Python

Tags: python

In Python, I don't know the meaning of the following usage:

```
sample[::-1]
```

Who knows that? Do you know what `[::-1]` means?

Comment: It's covered in the very beginning of any Python tutorial.

Comment: More context would be nice

Comment: This might come as a surprise, but [googling `python colon colon negative one`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+colon+colon+negative+one) actually turns up the answer to this question immediately.

Comment: This answer will explain it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/931095/2932244

Comment: @JRodDynamite Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> range(10)[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```